# How to increase MariaDB memory from my.cnf?

Tags: memory, centos, mysql, mariadb

I'm using Centos 7 and trying to increase MariaDB memory and performance and as I read before here I need to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but I can't find it in "/etc/my.cnf" file and here is the file content.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

am I doing something wrong or do I need to add all the variables in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

From Knowledge Base
[MariaDB Memory Allocation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-memory-allocation/),
section
[ENGINE=MEMORY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-memory-allocation/#enginememory):

> **How to Set Variables**
>
> In the text file my.cnf (my.ini on Windows), **add or modify a line** to
> say something like
>
> ```
> innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
> ```
>
> That is, VARIABLE name, "=", and a value. Some abbreviations are
> allowed, such as M for million (1048576), G for billion.
>
> For the server to see it, the settings must be in the "[mysqld]"
> section of the file.
>
> The settings in my.cnf or my.ini will not take effect until you
> restart the server.

If you don't see the line in your file, just add it in
(in the right section).